# Custom scrollable View within ScrollView

Tags: android, touch, scrollview

I created a custom View that implements a `GestureListener` and all the necessary logic to allow for some scrolling within the View. It works fine, as long as I do not put the View into some other scrollable View, e.g., a `ScrollView`.

If I wrap my View with a `ScrollView`, the touch events seem to be consumed by the `ScrollView` completely and are not handed through to my custom View. How can I tell the `ScrollView` that it should only consume touch events, if the touching happens *outside* of one of its children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request your scrollable container to not intercept touch events from your `View` by calling `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` on it when you receive an `ACTION_DOWN` event on your `View`.