# Swipe tabs with horizontal scrollview inside

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to have HorizontalScrollViews in the fragments of a Swipeable Tab - ViewPager.

My idea is that when you swipe your finger from say right to left, first the HorizontalScrollView scrolls to the right, and when it reaches the edge, the viewpager starts swiping to the next tab.

If I try to make it directly (just by putting the HorizontalScrollView in), then first the HorizontalScrollView gets the event and scrolls by a little (5-10 pixels) but then the viewpager catches the event and starts swiping.

I tried extending the HorizontalScrollView to prevent the viewpager from catching the event while it's scrolling, but when it reaches the edge I can't make it "intercept" it so he starts swiping.

My CustomHorizontalScrollView:

```
public class CustomHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
    private boolean scrolling = false;


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
        if(!isOnLeftEdge() && !isOnRightEdge()){
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
        if(!isOnLeftEdge() && !isOnRightEdge()){
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        if(!scrolling)
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            scrolling = true;
        else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            scrolling = false;

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


    private boolean isOnLeftEdge(){
        return getScrollX() == 0;
    }
    private boolean isOnRightEdge(){
        return getChildAt(0).getRight() == getWidth()+getScrollX();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can do that?

================= EDIT ======================

I tried to recreate the problem in a simple project. API 18 -> Blank Activity -> Navigation Type: Fixed Tabs + Swipe.

Then I create a test fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.provesandroid.CustomHorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.example.provesandroid.CustomHorizontalScrollView>
```

I edit the `MainActivity` to put the new fragment instead of the default:

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sv_fragment,
                container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And the `ScrollView`:

```
public class CustomHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
    }
    public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attr, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
        if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Now this was strange because using the default `HorizontalScrollView` the swiping between tabs would happen randomly. I think it has something to do with the speed or something of the finger movement.

But, as I said in the comments, with the new one the swiping between tabs doesn't happen at all.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21226087/3153792) to a similar question.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. This would disable completely the Scroll, as it doesn't get intercepted by the ScrollView.

Comment: Also, I tried making something like overriding the ViewPager onTouchEvent to allways call the ScrollView and check wether it's scrolling or not, and if it's in the edge or not... but it was too complicated I just throwed that away.

Comment: It is the `ViewPager` that is intercepting touch events from the `HorizontalScrollView` and not vice versa; you should be able to set a touch listener on the `HorizontalScrollView`, and disable the touch interception from the `ViewPager` when you receive an `ACTION_DOWN` event on it.

Comment: Yes, but that won't solve my problem. The code up there is actually a evolution of your proposal. Then the problem is that the `ViewPager` absolutely ignores all the swiping, since the first one, the `ACTION_DOWN`, it's being "disallowed" by the `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: Have you tried this out? It should only disallow interception of touch events, but if the touch event is not handled by the `HorizontalScrollView`, then it should be passed up to the `ViewPager` as per normal. Try it out, and report back if it doesn't work along with the details of your implementation.

Comment: The problem is that as the `HorizontalScrollView` covers all the screen, the touch event is allways handled by the `HorizontalScrollView`, thus disallowing the `ViewPager` to intercept the event allways. And I've told you, I did this before and what you see is an evolution of your solution, where I tried to disallow the interception only when the `HorizontalScrollView` is scrolling. But then when it's not scrolling, as the first touch event was not intercepted, the `ViewPager` just ignores all other ACTION_MOVE events.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed the `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` calls in your code. Also, it seems that `HorizontalScrollView` already handles this part on it's own. However, I just made a test project with the standard generated `ViewPager` + `Fragment` code, and added a `HorizontalScrollView` to the `Fragment`s, and it seemed to work as intended for non-edge scrolling. It looks like the problem is with your custom code, where you disable the interception  in all cases while the drag even is going on.

Comment: I just tried the default project and it still doesn't work. I updated my question including all the steps I did.

Comment: It is working fine for me on a Galaxy S2 device with the standard `HorizontalScrollView`. Your `CustomHorizontalScrollView` isn't working however.